# How to remove a file with specific filename in Linux from all the folders inside current directory?

Tags: linux, bash

My project has a number of directories and also has a large number of sub-projects. When I move from one PC to another all the Makefiles are creating problems in building the project.
If I remove the Makefiles then there is no error in building. How can I remove all the Makefile* files from the parent directory in Linux? Is there any command to perform this? There are hundreds of Makefiles. So removing them one by one is hard. Please suggest a method to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use -delete option.

```
find . -name "filename" -type f -delete
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Find#Delete_files_and_directories

Answer (score 1):

```
find . -name "name-here" -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

Comment: ...where `.` can also be replaced for the appropriate directory, so the command doesn't rely on relative paths.

Answer (score 0):

```
find . name "filename" -type f|xargs rm -rf
```